# replace double quote follow by quote (/")

Tags: shell, unix

how to replace double quote with escape char follow by quote ("/)

```
input: "ABC"|"CDS"|""gurgaon""|"ABC"|"CDS"|""gaon""

Output: "ABC"|"CDS"|"/"gurgaon"|"ABC"|"CDS"|"/"gaon
```

Comment: Shouldn't get this question a regex tag, too?

Comment: This helps? `$ echo $a`
"ABC"|"CDS"|""gurgaon""|"ABC" 

`$ echo $a | sed 's:\"\":\"\/\":g'`
"ABC"|"CDS"|"/"gurgaon"/"|"ABC"